# Does deploying flap change the aspect ratio of the wing?

Tags: flaps, high-lift-device

Specifically when a *Plain flap* is defleted the geometry of the wing will be altered (Camber is increased). Does this have any effect on aspect ratio? What's the connection between Camber and aspect ratio?

Comment: There is no connection. Aspect ratio is based on a projection of the wing in the x-y-plane. Camber is in z direction.

Comment: Short answer: it depends. Some flaps extend backward (increasing chord and thus reducing aspect ratio), other don't. See The section about [type of flaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flap_(aeronautics)#Types_of_flap) on the Wikipedia page so that you can evaluate if you want to restrict your question to specific type of flap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aspect ratio of a wing is [defined](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/geom.html) as:

$$ \text{AR} \equiv \frac{s^2}{A} , $$

where $s$ is the wingspan and $A$ is the total wing area.

Some types of flaps are not only increasing wing camber, but also the wing area:

> The Fowler, Fairey-Youngman and Gouge types of flap increase the wing area in addition to changing the camber.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flap_(aeronautics)#Types_of_flap))

Since the wingspan is unchanged, this will **decrease the aspect ratio**. Other types of flaps, like a **plain flap**, are **not changing the aspect ratio**.

You can see the flap types that change the aspect ratio in the following image (modified from [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Airfoil_lift_improvement_devices_(flaps).png)):

[image: Flaps]